# Want client-side Firebase logs to show up in StackDriver, not users' browsers

Tags: javascript, firebase, logging, google-cloud-functions, stackdriver

I'm using `firebase-functions/lib/logger` to log client-side firebase/firestore activity like

```js
const { log, error } = require("firebase-functions/lib/logger");

export const addData = async (userId, dataId) => {
  try {
    const collectionRef = firestore
      .collection("docs")
    await collectionRef.add({
      dataId,
    });
    log(`Data added`, { userId, dataId });
  } catch (err) {
    error(`Unable to add new data`, { userId, dataId });
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};
```

When I run this on my local, the log shows up in my browser console. Will this happen on non-local environments, ie for real users? Will these logs also show up automatically in Stackdriver, or are they stuck on the client side? I want to be able to view the logs either in Stackdriver or Firebase console but have them not show up in the browser for real users. How should I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Messages logged in Cloud Functions will not show up in the client app at all (that would probably be a security hole for your app).  They will show up in the Cloud Functions console in the log tab, and in StackDriver.

Any messages logged in your app will not show up in any Google Cloud product.  They are constrained to the device that generated them.  If you want cloud logging, you'll need to implement some other solution.  Cloud Functions does not support this - you will need to investigate other solutions or build something yourself.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess I figured since I was using a Firebase library to create these logs in the client they'd have some sort of hook into logging in the cloud associated with my Firebase app.